#  app for download in Titanium Studio

Tags: titanium-mobile

I'm trying to find more information about `Titanium` and I've been through some tutorials full of bad critics. Some say that Titanium is not able to do memory management as good as it should and that if we want complex applications we should use the native framework(`android, iphone`). I'm very new to Titanium and now I'm looking for a complex application which I would like to run and see how it works, but I cannot find one. Can someone give me a link with a complex example of app build in Titanium. The app should be either for iphone or android.

Thank you!

Comment: What sort of complexity you required?

Comment: It is not that important. Just an app with more than one page!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at Titanium's own KitchenSink app: http://developer.appcelerator.com/doc/kitchensink

It's an example app that shows most of Titanium's capabilities (GPS, camera, accelerometer, navigation tabs, splash screen, etc). You can get its source code from the link above.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a list of [Rich native applications on multiple platforms built with Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/showcase/applications-showcase/).